# For loop for form select getting results

Tags: php, arrays, forms, loops, select

i have the following code, it includes more rows each with a select list. I need to collect the results and pass through with the submit. 
The problem is that I don't know how many rows will there will be, so I need to use for loop. 
This way I cannot reference to $_POST['anything'], since it overrrides itself in every loop.
Pls help.

```
    <?php
print"<table class='pairs'>";
print"<tr>";
print"<td>";
print "<Form name='form5' method='post'>";
$numcols=4;
$sqlheaders=array("foo", "bar", "hallo", "world");
for($q=0;$q<$numcols;$q++)
{
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td>";
    print "sel_".$q;    
            print "</td>";
    print "<td>";
    print "no such data";
    print "</td>";
    print "<td>";
    print "<Select name='sel_'.$q????>";
    print "<option value='default'>...Choose</option>";

    foreach ($sqlheaders as $sqlheader)
        {
        print "<option value='sqlheader_'".$sqlheader."> $sqlheader</option>";  
        }
    print "</select>";
    print "</td>";
    print "</tr>";

}
print "<tr>";
print "<td>";
print "<Input type='hidden' name ='numcols' value ='$numcols' >";
print "<input type='submit' name='submit_uploadpairs' value='Mehet'/>";
print "</td>";
print "</tr>";
print "</Form>";

for($i=0;$i<$numcols;$i++)
{   
    $result=$_POST['sel_'?????];
    echo $result;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just name them something....

```
 print "<Select name='Dropdowns[$q]'>";
```

Then in you other loop...

```
for($i=0;$i<$numcols;$i++)
  {   
  $result=$_POST['Dropdowns'][$i];
  echo $result;
  echo "<br>";
 }
```

Comment: Hi again! Is there a way to tell how many items are there in the 'Dropdowns[$q]'? I mean yes, the initial value of the $q was equal to $numcols, but as I see the select doesn't pass on default values (eg. if you don't change to any list element). Therefore I can get less than $numcols. Thank you!